# Cannot allocate vector of size... - finding a way to divide calculation to smaller chunks

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, error-handling

While trying to calculate distances between points using

```
distm(FareStageMatrix, LSOACentroidMatrix, fun=distHaversine)
```

I am getting an error

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2453.7 Gb
```

I have around 800,000 records

What is the best way to divide the two matrices and then join everything back together?

I have now managed to compute it for first 10,000 records. How to automatize the process, i.e. I'm using

```
dist1 <- distm(FareStageMatrix[1:10000,], LSOACentroidMatrix[1:10000,], fun=distHaversine)
```

Comment: You can calculate on subsets of indexes. Making a grid with several evaluations like the first one you did.

Comment: I believe [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54971954/6574038) had a similar issue to yours.